# how to get image file size with php

Tags: php

I am trying to find a PHP function that will allow me to determine the file size of images uploaded. i.e. I want to block images over a certain size.

I tried using the `getimagesize();` function but this only seem to give the width and height of an image.

I have enclosed below the array values returned from  the getimagesize function. Unless i am mistaken, there is nothing in this array that relates to the actual file size

```
array(6) { [0]=> int(800) [1]=> int(800) [2]=> int(3) [3]=> string(24) "width="800" height="800"" ["bits"]=> int(music) ["mime"]=> string(9) "image/png" }
```

Comment: You're being deceived by the "image" part of your question. How do you determine the file size of a generic file? why would an image be different?

Comment: Exactly ^. You said it yourself, you need the file size of the image. So look for a function that gives you a file size instead of an image size.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 5):

You're being deceived by the "image" part of your question. How do you determine the file size of a generic file? why would an image be different?

Since images are files too, you should use the [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function provided by PHP

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
echo filesize($filename) . ' bytes';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try code    like this:

```
if($_FILES['image']['size'] <= 2097152 )
    {
    $uploaddir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/writereaddata/'; // destination folder



    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploaddir)) {


    }
    }
```

Comment: What's this, exactly?

Comment: this is for checking the filesize while uploading the image... above @andreea115 want to restrict the user to upload the images above the particular size..

Comment: I'd rephrase this question saying that inside `$_FILES['img_field_name']['size']` is stored the uploaded file size. I'd upvote that, but not the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function?

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy approach for that, first, determine the image URL, then check it's size as follows:

```
$image = get_headers("full-url-to-image", 1);
$bytes = $image["Content-Length"];
echo "$bytes";
```

That will echo image size in bytes for example:

```
length="12113"
```